# Can a bootstrap theme I created and connected to WordPress have plugins added, so I can add a news feed, events feed and calendar to my website pages?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

The site is a charity site, which is expected to have a news feed of goings on within the charity and events. Most of the home page is complete. But I don't know exactly how to write the code for an article in bootstrap, so that when I upload it to WordPress, it will interact properly. Allowing me to create new articles, remove old ones, etc. I either need to find out how to do this, or find out if I can use plugins to give me the same effect. This is my first time using WordPress. If you know of even a tutorial or something that helps with the news feed being built in bootstrap to work in WordPress, I would be over the moon. Thank you to anyone who offers their help!

I've tried to find an answer online but all I get are pre-built news theme suggestions. I guess there just that many it drowns out any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.

A bootstrap theme is just a static page. (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.) But WordPress creates all its pages dynamically. This is because all the blog posts are saved in a database. In order to work with WordPress, you would really need to use a WordPress theme. If you know PHP you could easily migrate your bootstrap theme to a WP theme.

There is even a bootstrap starter Theme which might help you to get started: https://de.wordpress.org/themes/wp-bootstrap-starter/

In this case you would really just need to add your markup, styles and scripts to the project.

Comment: So if I'm able to to migrate my bootstrap theme to WP then it would be possible at that point to add a news feed? I'm currently doing a tutorial that shows me how to do this. Another day or so and i should be connected to WP.